# how to get talend (TMAP) to load lookup data and incoming data at the same time

Tags: talend

I have a talend job that i require a lookup at the target table.
Naturally the target table is large (a fact table) so I don't want to have to wait to load the whole thing before going to running lookups like this picture below:

[image]

[image]
Is there a way to have the lookup work DURING the pull from the main source?
The attempt is to speed up the inital loads so things move fast, and attempt to save on memory. as you can see, the lookup is already passed 3 Million rows.

the tLogRow represents the same table as the lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you're looking for by configuring the lookup in your tMap to use "Reload at each row" lookup model, instead of "Load Once". This lookup model allows you to reexecute your lookup query for each incoming row, instead of loading all your lookup table at once, useful for lookups on large tables.
When you select the reload at each row model, you will have to specify a lookup key in the global map sections that will appear under the settings. Create a key with a name like "ORDER_ID", and map it with FromExt.ORDER_ID column. Then modify your lookup query so that it returns a single match for the ORDER_ID like so:
`"SELECT col1, col1.. FROM lookup_table WHERE id = '" + (String)globalMap.get("ORDER_ID") + "'"`.
This is supposing your id column is a string.
What this does is create a global variable called "ORDER_ID" containing the order id for every incoming row from your main connection, then executes the lookup query filtering for that id.